# Custom Radio button

Tags: android

i'm working on custom radio button. it works fine(as it is defined in options.xml) but when i switch from options.xml to main.xml, it turns default, means it is no more highlighted. it should work like until i press it it should not turn to default.. here is radiobutton_selector.xml

```
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_down" android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio" android:state_checked="false"/>
        </selector>
```

i'm using these in options.xml to call radio button settings.

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/sound"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0dp" >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:id="@+id/on"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:id="@+id/off"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
```

Please help me to figure  out the issue. Thanks in advance !!!!!

Comment: when i switch from options.xml to main.xml, it turns default?

Comment: have you maintain at boolean for RadioButton is Check true or false.

Comment: @ Samir Mangroliya   i use these in options.xml, when i pressed the radio button, it works fine, then i go to main.xml and then again go back to options.xml, it is not working(remain unpressed)

Comment: @ Herry ...  at boolean for RadioButton????

Comment: @user1296361 check my answer.If your Activity is destroy .then you need to use `SharedPreference` to stote int selection of Radio Button.

Comment: You could also do the trick with Toggle button. It's more elegant for that purpose.

Comment: @Nuno Gonçalves ...yeah it can be used...but problem is that my session is destroyed... is there any way to make my changes permanent until other one is pressed..

Comment: Well, I can see two ways of doing that. One using SharedPreferences API, which is more to be used between aplication usage, like exiting the aplication and save user preferences for example, and the other, not elegant, but works. Use a simple static variable where you save the state of the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this for your `RadioGroup`.
you need to save which radio Button you have selected ,for that you can use one variable like below.

```
int check_radio=-1;
public static final int RADIO_BUTTON_ON=1;
public static final int RADIO_BUTTON_OFF=2;

       mRadioGroup
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                            int checkedId) {

                        switch(checkedId){

                                            case R.id.on:
                                            //Radio Button on is True
                                            check_radio=RADIO_BUTTON_ON;
                     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                      editor.putInt("RadioButton", RADIO_BUTTON_ON);
                     // Commit the edits!
                     editor.commit();
                                            break;
                                           case R.id.off:
                                          //Radio Button off is True
                                           check_radio=RADIO_BUTTON_OFF;
                       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                      editor.putInt("RadioButton", RADIO_BUTTON_OFF);
                     // Commit the edits!
                     editor.commit();
                                          break;
                    }
                });
```

Now whey your Activity 's Resume you can check one condition like below.
Get Value from SharedPrefrence Like below code;

```
   //If you have save your value in SharedPrefrence it will return your stored int value.
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   check_radio = settings.getInt("RadioButton", -1);


  if(check_radio==RADIO_BUTTON_ON){
     mRadioOn.setChecked(true);
  }else if(check_radio==RADIO_BUTTON_OFF){
    mRadioOff.setChecked(true);
  }
```

you can use SharedPreferences by below step

```
   public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

Comment: ...no man...it is not working...same result... session destroyed

Comment: you can refer developer site for `SharedPreference` from this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.i also add my answer.when every you check Radio Button also save it's state in `SharedPreference` as i do in answer.

Comment: @Herry you could as well do it only on activity destroy. You don't need to be doing it everytime the user clicks on it. :)

Comment: @NunoGonçalves yes , you are right in this case .we can do that in OnDestoy.

Comment: Here is a tutorial about how to customize RadioButton and CheckBox in Android : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/934/customize-radiobutton-checkbox-android/