# How to set the height and width of a radio button?

Tags: android, html, css, radio-button

I am designing a form where I am putting two radio buttons. I want to increase the height and width of the radio button in HTML.

I got success in case of iOS but for Android I am not getting any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t change the height of a radio button in Android, because the radio button is a built-in control component and as such its size is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I found you can scale the radiobuttons with the CSS3 attribute `transform`.

For instance, you could do this: `-webkit-transform: scale(5);`.

Answer (score 0):

In xml file changing of height and width doesn't change anything so you can't change the height width of radio button or checkboxes
but the solution is that you can customize them

follow this link which may help you to create custom radio or checkboxes

[Custom Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152070/custom-radio-button)